# print elements by multiple tag names - msxml - xml parsing in C++

Tags: c++, xml-parsing, msxml, bstr

I am trying to parse xml file using MSXML , But I want to parse particular tags(nodes) not all nodes. Below two lines additional to the whole for xml parsing , gives output of all nodes. If I replace L" " to L"tag_name" ... I will get the results but I want to include more tags not just one. Please help.

//Variable with the name of node to find: 
   BSTR strFindText  = L" ";//" " means to output every node

Comment: It's not clear from your description what you are trying to achieve, but look at `IXMLDOMDocument::selectNodes` method. It lets you select a  set of nodes that satisfy an XPath expression.

Comment: I am using this pointer IXMLDOMNodeListPtr NodeListPtr; and  I am   //Collect all or selected nodes by tag name:
   NodeListPtr = docPtr->getElementsByTagName(strFindText); and my strFindText = L" " to select all nodes

Comment: So try `docPtr->selectNodes(L"tag1||tag2")`

Comment: Thank you, I tried but I am getting an exception.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It should be a single pipe. I think the right incantation is "//tag1 | //tag2", but I must admit my XPath is rather rusty.

Comment: Finally, I got it. But I did not use selectNodes method , instead passed another parameter to the parsing function and tweaked few if statements. And worked like a Charm !